# The use of H mass in mass defect and nuclear binding energy computations

Tags: physical-chemistry, protons

I've noted that introductory general chemistry texts compute the mass defect (or mass difference) for radioisotopes using the proton mass $m_\ce{H}=m_{\text{p}}\approx1.00783 \ \text{u} $, instead of $m_{\text{p}}\approx1.00728 \ \text{u}$, as per the Green Book (p. 93). This affects the results of succeeding nuclear binding energy computations.

Am I missing something here conceptually? Should the mass defect computation use the actual proton mass if it is readily available instead of the mass of $\ce{H}$?

Comment: It may depend on if the context evaluates mass defects for atoms or for nuclei.

Comment: @Poutnik This is for the mass defect for atoms. Now I wonder: is the mass of H used to account for the electrons present in the isotope?

Comment: Of course it is. The value 1.0078.. is for the complete H atom, roughly 0.0005 is the electron, so about 1.0073 is the proton.